# Oracle doing full table scan when converting timezone

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone, full-text-search

I have a table with a column of type timezone. This column is indexed.

This query uses the index:

```
select t.*
from <table> t
where t.load_date = to_timestamp('1 may 2013', 'dd mon yyyy') 
order by t.load_date;
```

This one (with the addition of the time zone conversion) does not, and hinting it to force index use does not work either:

```
select t.*
from <table> t
where t.load_date = to_timestamp('1 may 2013', 'dd mon yyyy') at time zone 'US/Pacific'
order by t.load_date;
```

Can someone explain why the latter query requires a FTS?

Thanks.

Comment: what data type is `load_date` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `load_date` is a `timestamp`, rather than a `timestamp with time zone`, the explain plan will show something like:

```
filter=SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("LOAD_DATE"))=
    SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(TIMESTAMP('2013-05-01 00:00:00000000000' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific'))
```

If the column was `timestamp with time zone` it would not have the `INTERNAL_FUNCTION()` call on the left-hand side, allowing it to be used for access (i.e. an index look-up) rather than just as a filter:

```
access(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC("LOAD_DATE")=
    SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(TIMESTAMP('2013-05-01 00:00:00000000000' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific'))
```

Your column is having to be internally converted from one type to the other, and that has to be done for every row before the converted value can be compared to your filter value. Oracle doesn't use the index in that case - it generally doesn't if an explicit or implicit function has to be applied to the indexed column.

(It could arguably use a full index scan to get the values to convert, but since it can't know how many will then match the filter it could end up having to retrieve so many rows from the actual table anyway that it would still end up more expensive. I don't know how it makes those kinds of decisions internally; in my experience it just ignores the index. Interestingly the `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC` call seems to be an exception to that).